# Opening Zip file containing files with same names

Tags: c#, zip

I am struggling with the problem with opening a zip file that contains two files with same name and path (appearantly zip format allows this for some reason). I am using C# System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open() method.

```
var zp = ZipPackage.Open(file,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read) as ZipPackage;
```

Since in my .zip file includes 2 files with exactly the same path the program crashes on attempt to add an existing key to a dictionary.
Did anyone have the same issue and how can I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get? Which line of code gives you that error?

Comment: The solution obviously is not to store data that doesn't fit in a dictionary in a dictionary. Use a list instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster The Package class contains field _zipArchive which contains property ZipFileInfoDictionary which is a Dictionary, where keys are file paths.

Comment: @DavidG - the line I posted when performing Open method. Error is "An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary"

Comment: Ah, so it's framework code that throws. Then consider using a library that does support this scenario, or try to find a way to enumerate the contents that doesn't use this dictionary.